# javascript show intro animation, then website

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have to add to an html page an intro animation. So I need that the first thing visible when loading the page is the gif at full screen (it takes about 2 seconds), then I have to fadeout the gif and fadein the html page. Can you help me?
My webpage is contained in a div like this:

```
<body>

    <div id="site">

        <div id="menu">
        ...
        </div>

        <div id="content">
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

What is contained in "site" must appear - fading -  after the gif intro has played and ended.

This is what I tried first:

```
<script>
$(window).ready(function() {
$('#intro').css('visibility','visible').hide().delay(3000).fadeIn(300);
$('#site').css('visibility','visible');
});
</script>
```

but I think it is not the right way.

Comment: Try it yourself first, then show us what you've done.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was me I'd put my gif in a DIV with and id on it outside of the site. Then using jQuery something like this:-

```
var timer = 0; //setting this up as global

$(document).ready( function () {

        $("#site").hide(); // you could have the site as display:none in css instead of this line.
        timer = setInterval( showSite , 2000 ) // here's your 2 seconds delay

});

function showSite() {
      clearInterval(timer);
      $("#myGIFdiv").fadeOut();
      $("#site").fadeIn();
}
```

I'd suggest a longer delay, as you don't know how long your gif will take to load ... look up preloading etc to find out more about that. This is a really crude example to get you started.

Comment: Hi, I have understood your example. I tried it, but it seems not working. Probably I'm missing some details on how to include this code. I put it within tags <script> ... </script> but it raise an error.

Comment: I'd messed up the code a bit ... I've corrected it now. You'll need to include jQuery of course, and also use CSS to position the two DIVs absolutely, so they can overlap (if that's what you want).

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to use css animations. it works without jquery and directly on the gif (no div needed)
the gif must have:

```
@keyframes customanim
{

0%   {values;}
100%   {values;}

}

@-webkit-keyframes customanim /* Safari and Chrome */
{

0%   {css-values;}
100%   {more-values;}

}

.animationclass {


position: absolute;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

animation: customanim 3s;

-webkit-animation: customanim 5s;

-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}
```

make sure you use "-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards" so the gif remains hidden after animation else the gif would return to its original state.

to play the animation again just execute this line in js:

`document.getElementById('objecttobeanimated').className ='animationclass';`

Link to W3C:

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp

hope i could help you

Comment: Thank you, but I haven't understood how to include this code in my project. I have to put it in css and rename .animationclass with the class of my gif, is it correct? And then?

Comment: Also, I see that IE9 and earlier don't support keyframe rule, and it is not accettable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

JS:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#preloader-anim").fadeOut(500);$("#preloader").delay(500).fadeOut(500);
});
```

CSS:

```
.preloader { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; background: #fff; z-index: 99999999; }
.preloader-anim { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -16px; margin-left: -16px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="preloader" class="preloader"><div id="preloader-anim" class="preloader-anim"><img src="http://www.iec.ch/img/loading_sliders_2.gif" /></div></div>
```

How it works:

A div id="preloader" is showed until the page is fully loaded. Then, fades out consecutively the loader.gif, and the div id="preloader".

Note: For illustration purposes I have used the first loading gif I found. It is not recommended to use hotlinking.